# Long click remove item from android listview

Tags: java, android

What I should write in the `onItemLongClick` function to remove an item from the listview on long click. Below is the code:

```
public class Favorites extends AppCompatActivity {

DBConnection db = new DBConnection(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_favorites);

     ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.empList);
     ArrayList<String> arrayList = db.getAllRecords();
     listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList));

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {



            return false;
        }
```

Comment: To remove it from the `ListView`, you just need to call `remove(position)` on the `ArrayList`, then `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `ArrayAdapter`. But I don't think that's all you're trying to do, is it?

Answer (score 2):

You should **setOnItemLongClickListener** for listView and define **adapter** to update data when remove item

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.empList);
    final ArrayList<String> arrayList = db.getAllRecords();
    final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            arrayList.remove(i);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much @nhonnq, your code working very well but when I run the code again, I found the same items that I deleted is remaining. In other words, at the run time, I can delete any items from the list. But when I close the app and run it again I see all items again.

Comment: you just remove item in arrayList so when you run app again arrayList has got at db (db.getAllRecords()). 
So you need remove data in database when delete

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used a custom Adapter class as a go between connecting the data to the ListView.  In this case, it would be something like the following:

```
Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this, arrayList);
String s = (String) arrayList.get(position);
arrayList.remove(s);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Take a look also at this repo:

https://github.com/CarmenDelessio/Hour8Application/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/bffmedia/hour8application

In particular, BaseAdapterActivity.java is worth using as a model.

Comment: unfortunately, it does't work. It gives me the error: cannot resolve methode notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: It has to call on object of Adapter .

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for removing an element from your array list

```
arrayList.remove(position);
```